# how to add binary imges From DataBase to Pdf using ItextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I'm working in Reports I use iTextSharp component. and it is working fine with me ... now I need to generate report which has some invoices that are saved in database as binary
the first page will be the report that I made it but when I generate the report  I want to add the invoices to the next pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not writing the whole code but will give you the overview of what is to be done.

I suppose that the invoice is an image stored in the database.

get the image from the database in a binary object.

To get the image in the binary form, use:

```
byte[] raw = (byte[])ds.Tables.Rows[i]["TiffImage"];//where ds is the dataset 
//in which you are getting your data and i is the ith row
```

now pass this byte stream to itextsharp image object and add it to the document. Refer: http://www.nerdyhearn.com/blog/176/

you can set the image height and width as well to fit into one page.

Comment: Hi saksham  Thanks for your help.. but I have many Invoices in Tiff file stored in DataDase as binary. how Can I Get each invoice in each page ...??

Comment: please see the edit. and be a bit more specific if you have any other doubt